# Mysql varbinary type row and invalid characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, varbinary

Unfortunately I've truncated my table, and when I want to import an backup I got some problems with the `VARBINARY(24)` type row.

**What is wrong with that?**

I want my field, to be like this: `ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713`

But when I'm using the following query:

```
UPDATE `proto` 
SET `vname` = 'ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713 ' 
WHERE `id` = 127;
```

The query is executing without any errors, but then I do:

```
SELECT `vname` 
FROM `proto` 
WHERE `id` = 127;
```

And I see that my `vname` field has the following data:

`c594c38ec4b9c38dc582c397c4bdc4b9c582c38e30373039`

instead of

`ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713`.

What is wrong with that and why I can not set my field data into: `ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713`?

Answer (score 2):

Your string is a unicode string. It is encoded in utf-8 encoding which can use multiple bytes for one character. So, your string corresponds to the following bytes sequence:

c5 94 c3 8e c4 b9 c3 8d c5 82 c3 97 c4 bd c4 b9 c5 82 c3 8e 30 37 30 39 30 35 2d 31 32 31 37 31 33

Your column is declared as VARBINARY(24), so your data don't fit into the column and are truncated. Only 24 bytes are stored:

c5 94 c3 8e c4 b9 c3 8d c5 82 c3 97 c4 bd c4 b9 c5 82 c3 8e 30 37 30 39

That is what you see.

To solve the problem, set the type of your column to VARCHAR(24), so that the limit is applied to the number of characters, not bytes. Set the encoding for your table to "utf-8". If you can set the connection encoding, let it also be "utf-8" (looks like it already is "utf-8"). Then everything will be OK.

If you don't want to make your column VARCHAR, you can just double the capacity of your VARBINARY. Let it be VARBINARY(48). But I don't recommend this. Although most 24-char utf-8-encoded  strings will fit into 48 bytes, some of them will not (because some exotic characters can take more then 2 bytes. In theory, the length of one character in utf-8 can be up to 6 bytes! Very rarely though...). If you make your column VARCHAR this will be the best option, because in fact you put there text, not binary data.

Comment: Aight, thanks ! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Merry Christmas! (+1 for now).

Comment: Well, I'm using phpMyAdmin. I've set the encoding for the table to `utf-8_general_ci` and the problem still occur, while executing the following query: `UPDATE items SET name =  'ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713 ';`. I'm getting this warning: `Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1` and then the `name` field I wanted to modify looks like this: `c594c38ec4b9c38dc582c397c4bdc4b9c582c38e30373039`. (Read the next comment).

Comment: Have you changed the type of the column form VARBINARY to VARCHAR, as I advised?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass binary data as a sequence of characters, the encoding issues may raise. The server have to figure out what binary data do you mean, when you send "ŔÎĹÍł×ĽĹłÎ070905-121713" and this depends on the encoding selected for your connection. Try to check if it is correct.

In general, I prefer passing binary data as hexadecimal (like x'123AB45CD789EF0123'), but as far as I understand, you already have a table backup, where the data are represented as characters, so this is not an option for you.

Comment: How can I check the encoding for my connection?

Comment: This depends on which tool you use to communicate with the server... This should be one of parameters when you establish the connection.

Comment: By the way, you can also check the encoding of your server/database/table to match the encoding of your data.

Comment: And another comment: your string looks like unicode. May be, it is utf-8-encoded? Then it won't fit into the varbinary(24) and will be truncated. Why don't you use varchar type? Well, I think, I should post another answer, because now I see what happens.